# PayPal validation fails for some usernames

Tags: c#, .net, utf-8, paypal-ipn, asp.net-webpages

I validate a PayPal request received in an ASP WebPage by POSTing it back to PayPal with the following method:

```
    public bool ValidateRequest(HttpRequest request)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("cmd=_notify-validate");
        foreach (string paramName in request.Form)
        {
            var paramValue = UrlEncode(request.Form[paramName]);
            sb.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", paramName, paramValue);
        }
        var parameters = sb.ToString();
        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameters);

        var webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var uploadData = webClient.UploadData(validatingUrl, "POST", data);
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(uploadData);

        return message == "VERIFIED";
    }
```

This code worked flawlessly for the last two years until I received a payment from a user with name Ramón Martín. This is how his name is logged from the IPN:

> last_name=Mart�n&first_name=Ram�n

The method above works well with Chinese, Japanese and Russian names. Any ideas how to fix it for the current case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the default encoding for the PayPal buttons was windows-1252.
It must be changed to UTF-8.

You can do it fro PaPal -> My Profile -> My Selling Tools -> PayPal button language encoding -> More options -> UTF-8

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the encoding format to windows-1252? In your code, you have set it to UTF-8 and the name given I can see the Ó and the í. Try to use windows-1252 encoding and see if its give you another relieve.